# how to Change Random Color in Python

Tags: python, colors, fonts

choose='''
Please Choose an Option

```
1. Encrypt
2. Decrypt
3. Exit
```

'''
this is my code I want to change its color randomly
like If I choose Option 1 and after successfully completion this phase the all of Choose String Color should be change to another color
please any Solution ?? In Python

Comment: Question really not clear, perhaps try to rephrase it!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.